# In Nextjs 14, one of my route is marked as dynamic during build time. What is causing it to be dynamic

Tags: next.js

I have a file route.ts. The path is `src\app\api\user\create\route.ts`

```
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";

export async function POST() {
  const post = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email: "createuser2@example.com",
      name: "createuser2",
      posts: {
        create: [
          {
            title: "This is user 2",
            published: false,
            categories: {
              connectOrCreate: {
                where: {
                  id: 3,
                },
                create: {
                  name: "Machine Learning",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(post));
}
```

When I run npm run build. I see that this route is marked as dynamic.

```
├ λ /api/user/create                     0 B                0 B
```

I don't know what is present in this code that is making this route as dynamic. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: its looks like your url is getting appended somehow with the values? maybe your frontend is doing a /api/user/create?email:"createuser2@example.com"&name: "createuser2" instead of just calling the api/user/create with the data?

Comment: @KingJoeffrey It's just an api route that I am currently calling from postman to create some records in db. It's not getting called from front end yet.

Answer (score 0):

API usually are usually dynamics since you will almost always "do something".

Here you save to a DB and, even if your data is the same for now, you would get an ID after the insert which is impossible to know at build time. So the data you return would always change hence not static...

Comment: I don't agree to it as there are other api routes as well in my build output. These api calls are making get calls to database to fetch some data and these are marked as `static` in the build output -
`
├ ○ /api/post                            0 B                0 B
├ ○ /api/post/aggregate                  0 B                0 B
├ ○ /api/post/group                      0 B                0 B
├ ○ /api/post/order                      0 B                0 B`